# Can't get public info using Facebook Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get public profile using user_token. I registered FB app and get user_token from page: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/
but when I try to get public profile https://graph.facebook.com/100000378611443?limit=1000&access_token={user_token}
I see an error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "The global ID 100000378611443 is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

But if I use user_token in above URL from another my app I can successfully get public user profile.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since v2.0 of Facebook API apps are no longer allowed to use global IDs, just app-scoped ID. These ID are generated when a user logs in onto your application.

If you are attempting to retrieve current logged in user's information, you should use `/me` endpoint along with the user's access token: `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={user_token}`

Note that with these new scoped IDs, apps are **not** allowed to retrieve any data from users who haven't gave permissions to the app.

Cheers

Comment: I try to get info from other user profile.
If you have any {user_token} you can get public info from profile and public posts from other users. This URL have to work, but it doesn't:
https://graph.facebook.com/100000378611443?limit=1000&access_token={user_token}
Also I don't understand why user_token from my first app allow me to get public info, but uset_token from my new created app doesn't allow to do this.

Comment: Because if you are using v2.0 you will not get data from users that are not using your app. Even if the data is public.

Comment: It's all explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_api_versions

Comment: Thanks for answers! I read changes in API 2.0 and now I can't understand how I can get basic info about user from my APP? I mean how to convert global ID to app specific ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the older version of Facebook Graph API V1.0 which will continue to exist until April 30th, 2015.

https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/100000378611443

Answer (score 0):

You must use access token, not user token! You can obtain one from  Graph API Explorer here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer 
Then you must have at least user_about_me permission to get profile data. As many user data permissions you have, as many endpoints and data you obtain. Keep in mind, access token you get from Graph API Explorer is short living - expires in an hour or so. More about tokens and their terms here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me too, trying to using "Graph Api Explorer" with an user id obtained debugging my application.

User id that obtain from a call as:

```
 ../<event_id>/likes
```

isn't **REAL** user id, but a kind of id "encrypted" (let me use the word) with access_token.

So if you wanna test that user id on GAE, you need to specify also access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<user_id>?access_token=<application_access_token>
```